# Creating isolated Jupyter ipython kernels with pyenv: No module ipykernel_launcher found

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pyenv

I've spent hours scouring the internet for a fix but I'm still unable to find a solution to my problem.

I've created a virtual env named "playground" using `pyenv` and installed `ipykernel` within:

```
cd playground

user@Jerome-Ko-Jia-Jin playground % pip3 list
Package           Version
----------------- -------
appnope           0.1.2
backcall          0.2.0
decorator         5.0.7
ipykernel         5.5.3
ipython           7.23.0
ipython-genutils  0.2.0
jedi              0.18.0
jupyter-client    6.1.12
jupyter-core      4.7.1
matplotlib-inline 0.1.2
numpy             1.20.2
pandas            1.2.4
parso             0.8.2
pexpect           4.8.0
pickleshare       0.7.5
pip               20.2.3
prompt-toolkit    3.0.18
ptyprocess        0.7.0
Pygments          2.9.0
python-dateutil   2.8.1
pytz              2021.1
pyzmq             22.0.3
setuptools        49.2.1
six               1.15.0
tornado           6.1
traitlets         5.0.5
wcwidth           0.2.5

pyenv which python
/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/playground/bin/python
```

Added kernel.json with the following:

```
user@Jerome-Ko-Jia-Jin ~ % jupyter --paths
config:
    /Users/user/.jupyter
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/etc/jupyter
    /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    /etc/jupyter
data:
    /Users/user/Library/Jupyter
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
runtime:
    /Users/user/Library/Jupyter/runtime
user@Jerome-Ko-Jia-Jin ~ % jupyter --paths
config:
    /Users/user/.jupyter
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/etc/jupyter
    /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    /etc/jupyter
data:
    /Users/user/Library/Jupyter
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
runtime:
    /Users/user/Library/Jupyter/runtime

python -m ipykernel install --user --name playground --display-name "Playground"

cd /Users/user/Library/Jupyter/kernels/playground
user@Jerome-Ko-Jia-Jin playground % cat kernel.json
{
 "argv": [
  "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/playground/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Playground",
 "language": "python"
}%
```

Ran Jupyter notebook and switched to the new "Playground" kernel but I'm getting this error:
`/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/playground/bin/python: No module named ipykernel_launcher`

Could someone please enlighten me here? I tried reinstalling `ipykernel` but it still doesn't work.

Thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: I have the same issue on NixOS. I run JupyterLab with a separate `nix-shell`, and try to add kernels from virtualenvs. Some do work, some crash with `No module named ipykernel_launcher`. However, `python -c "import ipykernel_launcher"` works just fine in those virtualenvs. And I've used output of `pip list --format=freeze` from the JupyterLab environment in `pip install --constraint constraints.txt ipykernel` in the virtualenv, so ipykernel versions should be compatible.